# EJB TimerService thread priority

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, openejb

I use OpenEJB timerService.createCalendarTimer() to schedule tasks, similar to [this example](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/schedule-expression/README.html)

My problem is that with time, the accuracy of the timer deteriorates and "checkOnTheDaughters" is not called every second. I need to make sure the method is called as scheduled.

How can this be achieved?

One option I think of is setting high priority to the appropriate thread. May it help?

How EJB TimerService thread priority can be set?

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ) // allows timers to execute in parallel
@Startup
public class FarmerBrown {


    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void construct() {
        final TimerConfig plantTheCorn = new TimerConfig("plantTheCorn", false);
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(new ScheduleExpression().month(5).dayOfMonth("20-Last").minute(0).hour(8), plantTheCorn);
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(new ScheduleExpression().month(6).dayOfMonth("1-10").minute(0).hour(8), plantTheCorn);

        final TimerConfig harvestTheCorn = new TimerConfig("harvestTheCorn", false);
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(new ScheduleExpression().month(9).dayOfMonth("20-Last").minute(0).hour(8), harvestTheCorn);
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(new ScheduleExpression().month(10).dayOfMonth("1-10").minute(0).hour(8), harvestTheCorn);

        final TimerConfig checkOnTheDaughters = new TimerConfig("checkOnTheDaughters", false);
        timerService.createCalendarTimer(new ScheduleExpression().second("*").minute("*").hour("*"), checkOnTheDaughters);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void timeout(Timer timer) {
        if ("plantTheCorn".equals(timer.getInfo())) {
            plantTheCorn();
        } else if ("harvestTheCorn".equals(timer.getInfo())) {
            harvestTheCorn();
        } else if ("checkOnTheDaughters".equals(timer.getInfo())) {
            checkOnTheDaughters();
        }
    }

    private void plantTheCorn() {
        // Dig out the planter!!!
    }

    private void harvestTheCorn() {
        // Dig out the combine!!!
    }

    private void checkOnTheDaughters() {
        checks.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int getChecks() {
        return checks.get();
    }
}
```